# GDB affecting setcontext result

Tags: c, gdb

I'm working on some code that requires that I manually manipulate the context of a section of code and then switch to it, rather than using makecontext. My test program fails on a line due to an assertion failure, so I tried using GDB to determine the result of that and to see why that section failed, however, when I run it with GDB v7.4.1, it segfaults due to a null address on an earlier section of code.

The result of the context switch is as follors: the program's instruction pointer points to the beginning of a function which takes in two parameters, a pointer to another function, and some argument. (The function passes the argument into the function pointer, and then switches the context back).

I isolated the area of code that's causing this, and here is the result of the code around that.

```
245 setcontext(runQueue->front->currContext);
(gdb) print runQueue->front->currContext->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]
$1 = 420391
(gdb) print runQueue->front->currContext->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RSP]
$2 = 1077936128
(gdb) print runQueue->front->currContext->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RDI]
$3 = 4199321
(gdb) print runQueue->front->currContext->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RSI]
$4 = 10
```

This is just before where the context is switched. I checked the registers to verify that the values were correct for the context that the program is switching to, and they are as expected (REG_RIP: 4203091 == 0x402253, REG_RSP: 1077936128 == 0x40400000, REG_RDI: 4199321 == 0x401399, and REG_RSI: 0xa == 10)

After stepping into the context switch and following it out of the change in context, the result is this:

```
thread_func(function=0, arg=0x0) at thread.c:51
51 {
(gdb) info registers rip
rip      0x402253 0x402253 <thread_func>
(gdb) info registers rsp
rsp      0x40400000       0x40400000
(gdb) info registers rdi
rdi      0x401399 4199321
(gdb) info registers rsi
rsi      0xa      10
```

The values of the registers are unchanged, but the arguments are not passed in correctly by GDB, the program attempts to utilize the 0 values, and the program segmentation faults for accessing a null pointer.

Is there any way to fix this or get around this?

Comment: Rather than use screenshots, copying the text/information into your post would be preferable.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code of `setcontext()` and/or whatever is calling `thread_func()`.

Comment: `setcontext()` is from ucontext.h, when it is called, it executes a context switch, causing the instruction pointer to point to `thread_func()`, so it isn't actually being called.

Comment: I see - so you say that you're not using `makecontext()` to set up the `ucontext_t` structure - how are you doing that? I assume the platform is Linux x86_64?  Finally, some C and assembly code from thread_func() might be helpful - at the very least the prototype for the function.

Comment: I first malloc a new ucontext_t, I get the current context, and I only edit the RIP to point to thread_func(), the RSP to a mmap-ed stack, RDI to another function, and RSI to the argument for the other function. The prototype for thread_func: `void thread_func(void(*function)(void *), void *arg) { int returnVal; function(arg); returnVal = thread_exit(THREAD_SELF); exit(0); }`

Comment: As for assembly:
`push   %rbp
mov   %rsp,%rbp
sub   $0x20,%rsp
mov   %rdi, -0x18(%rbp)
mov   %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
mov   -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
mov   -0x18(%rbp),%rax
mov   %rdx,%rdi
callq *%rax
mov   $0xfffffffe,%edi
callq 0x402a0d <thread_exit>
mov   %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
cmpl  $0xfffffffc,-0x4(%rbp)
je    0x40229c <thread_func+73>
mov   $0x4044c2,%ecx
mov   $0x3f,%edx
mov   $0x404300,%esi
mov   $0x404309,%edi
callq 0x400940 <__assert_fail@plt>
mov   $0x0,%edi
callq 0x4009e0 <exit@plt>`

Comment: I am not having this problem with a simple program designed to do what you're describing (with gcc 4.8.1 and gdb 7.6.1). In my test program `thread_func()` is given a pointer to a function that calls `printf()` to format the argument, and all that works fine.  I think that Employed Russian is right that you may be misinterpreting the arguments displayed by gdb too early in the `thread_func` prologue. What happens if you `stepi` through the first 9 instructions of `thread_func()`?  I'll bet you end up at whatever function is at `0x401399` with `0xa` in `rdi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The values of the registers are unchanged, but the arguments are not passed in correctly by GDB, the program attempts to utilize the 0 values, and the program segmentation faults for accessing a null pointer.

It is exceedingly likely that your interpretation of what's happening is incorrect.

In particular, you claim that the NULL dereference is happening appears to largely be based on this:

```
thread_func(function=0, arg=0x0) at thread.c:51
```

where the values of function and arg should be `0x401399` and `0xa` respectively.

However, your function has a prolog, and you've stopped *before* that prolog has executed. GDB is showing you values currently contained at memory locations that *will* contain the arguments after the prolog, but you haven't yet stored them there. Try to `stepi` past prolog (past instruction `mov %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)`), and you will observe that `function` and `arg` magically acquire correct values.

If your program later crashes with a NULL pointer dereference, that is happening because of something else.

P.S. In setting up `%rsp`, you are violating the ABI requrements: x86_84 requires that inside each function, `%rsp` is 16-byte aligned. That means that *on entry* to any function `%rsp&0xF == 8` (you have `%rsp&0xF == 0`). This could well cause a crash later, especially if you use any SSE2 instructions.

You can fix this by setting `%rsp` to `mmap_addr+8`, or by compiling `thread.c` with `-mstackrealign`.

Comment: You were right, it was the ABI requirement for the 16-byte alignment. Thanks!